# ECS Fargate - Is it possible to create container instances dynamically?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am working on a project where it is required to create multiple instance of container dynamically based on the count received from the AWS Lambda function. Each container will execute its own task. I have done a lot of research but still not sure how to achieve this. Also how to delete the container instance when the task execution is completed?

Answer (score 1):

You're describing the use case [AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) has been built for. It essentially allows you to submit tasks that are being processed in Docker Containers and manages the lifecycle of those containers for you. Since [pre:invent 2020 it also supports Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-fully-serverless-batch-computing-with-aws-batch-support-for-aws-fargate/).

An alternative would be using a Step Function that processes the output of the Lambda function and dynamically creates ECS tasks for that. Tasks without a service, so they just terminate when they're done processing. Depending on the amount of jobs you have I'd prefer AWS Batch.

Comment: Will i be able to pass the data to containers if i will go with the alternative solution which you have mentioned?

Comment: Yes, you can do that - have a look a [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-a-simple-fetch-and-run-aws-batch-job/) for an example.